# Shell script to backup directories

Tags: shell-script, eclipse

I'm running eclipse on windows and would like to automatically backup my src direcories for all my projects. I installed cygwin and tried to make a simple backup script but I am having trouble properly specifying the destination filename. The backups should be in the current directory.directory of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash


for f in /cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/USERNAME/My\ Documents/Eclipse\ Workspace/*
do
        echo "in folder \"$f\""
        cp -a "$f"/src/ ./????.bak

done
```

I would like ???? to be the project folder (not the absolute path). Thanks.

Comment: `rsync` is a good tool to maintain backups. It only copies the files which are changed. instead of the whole bunch of files. 
http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: There are also incremental backup tools (based on `rsync`) like e.g. [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/). But rather follow @Gilles's and @sparticvs's advice: revision control!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the shell construct you're looking for is [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname).

```
for f in /cygdrive/c/Documents\ and\ Settings/USERNAME/My\ Documents/Eclipse\ Workspace/*
do
    cp -a "$f/src/" "./$(dirname "$f").bak"
done
```

But really, this is not a good backup solution. Every time you run the copy, the previous state is erased. And it doesn't provide any history at all. **Use version control**. Use anything, even [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) (the useful functions of which can be learned in under an hour). Whichever version control system you choose:

1. Create a repository.
2. Check in or import your existing files.
3. Whenever you've done a little chunk of work, commit.

Comment: People only start using version control after a bad experience with a backup script :)

Comment: I would normally set up a git repo but I wanted to practice my shell scripting.

Comment: in the end I settled with `cp -a "$f"/src/ "./backup/$(basename "$f").bak"`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a source code management system like git or hg (mercurial). If they are private projects BitBucket has a nice private project storage for free (given its less than 10 people on the project).  Git works well on Windows and there is a plugin for eclipse called EGIT which would allow you to sync to a repo elsewhere. For programming, I would definitely recommend this over writing backup scripts.